How to release USDZ model resources after exiting ImmersiveSpace in visionOS?
Background: This is a simple visionOS empty application. After the app launches, the user can enter an ImmersiveSpace by clicking a button. Another button loads a 33.9 MB USDZ model, and a final button exits the ImmersiveSpace.
Below is the memory usage scenario for this application:

After the app initializes, the memory usage is 56.8 MB.
After entering the empty ImmersiveSpace, the memory usage increases to 64.1 MB.
After loading a 33.9 MB USDZ model, the memory usage reaches 92.2 MB.
After exiting the ImmersiveSpace, the memory usage slightly decreases to 90.4 MB.

Question: While using a memory analysis tool, I noticed that the model's resources are not released after exiting the ImmersiveSpace. How should I address this issue?
Robot.usdz Memory
struct EmptDemoApp: App {

    @State private var appModel = AppModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(appModel)
        }

        ImmersiveSpace(id: appModel.immersiveSpaceID) {
            ImmersiveView()
                .environment(appModel)
                .onAppear {
                    appModel.immersiveSpaceState = .open
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    appModel.immersiveSpaceState = .closed
                }
        }
        .immersionStyle(selection: .constant(.mixed), in: .mixed)
     }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(AppModel.self) private var appVM
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                ToggleImmersiveSpaceButton()
            }
            
            if appVM.immersiveSpaceState == .open {
                Button {
                    Task {
                        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Robot", withExtension: "usdz") {
                            if let model = try? await ModelEntity(contentsOf: url, withName: "Robot") {
                                model.setPosition(.init(x: .random(in: 0...1.0), y: .random(in: 1.0...1.6), z: -1), relativeTo: nil)
                                appVM.root?.add(model)
                                print("Robot: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(model).toOpaque())")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Add A Robot")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @Environment(AppModel.self) private var appVM

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            appVM.root = content
        }
    }
}

struct ToggleImmersiveSpaceButton: View {
    @Environment(AppModel.self) private var appModel
    @Environment(\.dismissImmersiveSpace) private var dismissImmersiveSpace
    @Environment(\.openImmersiveSpace) private var openImmersiveSpace

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            Task { @MainActor in
                switch appModel.immersiveSpaceState {
                    case .open:
                        appModel.immersiveSpaceState = .inTransition
                        appModel.root = nil
                        await dismissImmersiveSpace()

                    case .closed:
                        appModel.immersiveSpaceState = .inTransition
                        switch await openImmersiveSpace(id: appModel.immersiveSpaceID) {
                            case .opened:
                                break

                            case .userCancelled, .error:
                                fallthrough
                            @unknown default:
                                appModel.immersiveSpaceState = .closed
                        }

                    case .inTransition:
                        break
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Text(appModel.immersiveSpaceState == .open ? "Hide Immersive Space" : "Show Immersive Space")
        }
        .disabled(appModel.immersiveSpaceState == .inTransition)
        .animation(.none, value: 0)
        .fontWeight(.semibold)
    }
}


It looks like you are storing everything in that root variable. Try clearing it but it could be an issue to keep a reference to content somewhere outside of RealityView

Thank you. I set the root to nil before exiting the ImmersiveSpace, but it still didn't remove the cached model resources. I also tried removing all entities before exiting the ImmersiveSpace, but that didn't work either.
Through testing, I found that if I load a pure Mesh model (without materials), the cache is released correctly. Therefore, I suspect that the issue with the unreleased resources is caused by the material (texture). However, even when I set the model's material to nil, it still didn't solve the problem.

It is probably leaking, my point is that it doesn’t seem like good practice to do that.

You are right. The leak tool show two tip, but it's unavailable to me.
